# Any equivalent to '-c:v copy' for changing container of webm to mp4 video client-side in JS?

Tags: javascript, video, ffmpeg, mp4, mediarecorder

Exploring the [Mediarecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) and really hope to get an mp4 output instead of webm. Prefer to stay client-side to reduce server resources and [ffmpeg.js](https://github.com/muaz-khan/Ffmpeg.js) at 17mb doesn't seem viable for online use.

Discovered that one can create (Chrome/Firefox) a webm/h.264, which converts [*without* re-encoding](https://superuser.com/a/479128) to an mp4 using FFMPEG. The resulting file opens fine in Quicktime MacOS ([snippet source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417952/convert-webm-h-264-to-mp4-h-264-efficiently-with-ffmpeg-js#comment77816196_45417952)):
`ffmpeg -i _inputfile_.webm -c:v copy _outputfile_.mp4`

Whereas this [clever hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44398123/10885535) works to display the video *maybe* as an mp4 in the browser, but the downloaded file won't open in Quicktime (just VLC, same for webm):

```
new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/mp4'});
video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(superBuffer);
```

Therefore, wondering if there's another JS hack to do what FFMPEG's `-c:v copy` does, but to the blob bytes of the MediaRecorder's `recordedBlobs` and give it the same mp4 container that's accepted by Quicktime/etc?

[Pastebin of current setup](https://pastebin.com/EvP3J9yd)

Comment: Why do you prefer mp4 over webm? I have the opposite preference.

Comment: Forgot to mention – for offline (out of browser) usage as it's capturing from the HTML5 Canvas (displaying p5.js content). Want to be able to display on mediaplayers, share/upload creations to social media or video streaming sites. Most of which only take mp4.

Comment: Show the complete log from your ffmpeg command.

Comment: Here's [a pastebin log](https://pastebin.com/3wfgpTXR) from the command: `ffmpeg -i test.webm -c copy test.mp4`

Comment: You may have to re-encode. Perhaps it doesn't like the Baseline profile (compared to the much more common Constrained Baseline, Main, and High profiles).

Comment: Hmm but the output file opens just fine in Quicktime/etc, so I don't know why re-encoding should be necessary.